# mongoose error while trying to post with duplicate entries but only for email,why?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose model which collects data like name,email,date etc.It's to store the registered projects information.Now one person can register with multiple projects as per my use case.But when I try to store documents with duplicates it get's inserted except for the email,it shows error.

error :  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: netninja.conduct_events.$email_1 du
p key: { : "latha98@gmail.com" }'

my code is something like this,

model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-type-url');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const conductEventSchema = new Schema({
  name:{
    type:String
  },
  email:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    trim:true
  },
  date1:{
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now
  },
  date2:{
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now
  },
  date_from:{
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now
  },
  date_to:{
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now
  },
  event_type:{
    type:String
  },
  phoneno1:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  phoneno2:{
    type:String
  },
  reason:{
    type:String
  },
  experience:{
    type:String
  },
  nativity:{
    type:String
  },
  event_name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  event_description:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  url:{
    type:mongoose.SchemaTypes.Url
  },
  strength:{
    type:Number
  },
  utility1:{
    type:String
  },
  utility2:{
    type:String
  }
})

const Conduct_events = mongoose.model('conduct_events',conductEventSchema);

module.exports = Conduct_events;
```

I didn't add any schema validation stating the email to be unique.But it's giving me error.I have similar types of forms to be used in many places.So it will be helpful if I got rid of this.Please help me with it.I referred the answers related to this question but couldn't get yet.And what is that $email_1 in the error?

Comment: Drop your index by running `Model.dropIndex({ email: 1 });`

Comment: Thanks it worked,but could you please explain why that index is created.I am using mLab to view documents.I found the index there and deleted it manually.But why the system creates that index or indexes in general.

Comment: Because at the time of schema creation you might did this  `email:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    trim:true, unique: true
  }`... And if it would have been created then we need to drop it either by query or manually

Comment: Ok,I got it.Thanks